# How to use an if expression in Binding WPF - c#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

Here is my code:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="viewTicket" Style="{StaticResource ticketListBox}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Background="Transparent" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" SelectionChanged="ViewTicket_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Visibility="{Binding selectedCheck}" Name="check" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="../../Images/check-donatota.png" Stretch="None" MouseLeftButtonUp="Check_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
                    <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding selectedQuantity}" Name="quantity" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding amount}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding name}"/>
                    <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding selectedPrice}" Name="price" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding total, StringFormat=C}"/>
                    <Image Visibility="{Binding selectedTrash}" Name="trash" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,15,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="../../Images/trash-donatota.png" Stretch="None" MouseLeftButtonUp="Trash_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
                </Grid>

                <ListView 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ingredients}" 
                    Grid.Row="1" 
                    Margin="-5,0,0,0" 
                    Name="viewTicketIngs" 
                    IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                    Style="{StaticResource ticketListBox}"
                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                    Background="Transparent" 
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                    BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
                    SelectionChanged="ViewTicketIngs_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Visibility="Visible" Name="quantity" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="{DynamicResource GrayTextDonaTotaBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding amount}"/>
                                <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{DynamicResource GrayTextDonaTotaBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ing.name}"/>
                                <TextBlock Visibility="Visible" Name="price" Grid.Column="2" Foreground="{DynamicResource GrayTextDonaTotaBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding total, StringFormat=C}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I add data to the `ListView` `viewTicket`, but depending of a property I would like to change the `ItemSource` Binding of the `ListView` `viewTicketIngs`. In other words, is there anyway that I can use an if expression on the binding? Something like `ItemsSource="{Binding IF(mode == 0) {ingredients} else {plates}}"`

Comment: Perhaps create a `ListView`  [`<DataTemplate.Triggers>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatemplate.triggers?view=netframework-4.8) but have it bound to `mode`  on your ViewModel

Comment: As a note, since you are not setting the ListView's View property and just assign a simple ItemTemplate, you may as well use a ListBox, i.e. the base class of ListView. It is just simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Binding by a DataTrigger in a Style:

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ListView">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding plates}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding mode}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ingredients}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Style>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score -1):

As I understand it, you sometimes dispaly plates, sometimes ingredients. Now there are triggers conditional display. WPF actually has a pretty wide support.

However what might be better is to have 2 different ViewModel classes and two (how I call them) "type targetting data tempaltes". Say you have these clases:

```
abstract class ViewModelItem { }

class Plate : ViewModelItem { }

class IngredientsList : ViewModelItem { }
```

The propety you exposie this in, would be set to `ViewModelItem`. In realtiy you would assign either a `Plate` or `IngredientsList` Instance.

Now you define two DataTemplates. A interesting thing about WPF is that if you do not specify a explicit Template, the Code will go out of it's way to try to find one. And it will do the matching via the [DataType property of the Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype?view=netframework-4.8) (TargetType for Styles and similar). It works similar to what CSS does, with somebodies code going out of it's way to find a template to apply.

Comment: @Clemens I do feel like it was the wrong question. Ingredients and Plates does not sound like the two cases have enough in common to be even handeled by the same ViewModel class. Brothers in the class Heirarchy? Maybe. Same class? Propably not. And not a lot of people know about Type Targetting Data Templates wich might be the easier solution to the bigger problem.

Comment: All that is completely irrelevant to the question. "*Type Targetting Data Templates*", seriously? Where's the context here? OP just wants to switch between two source collections.

Comment: @Clemens Why did you delete your original comment that I replied to? Also, why use Multibinding when this way is propably cleaner? It looks like your answer was not any closer on target then mine, so you are hardly in a position to talk down to me.

Comment: Your post is not actually an answer to the question. It does in no way address the problem how to switch between two Bindings to two different properties when some other property changes. I'm also not suggesting to use a MultiBinding, see my answer. In case you are referring to my comment on the other answer, please let me know if you don't understand it.

Comment: @Clemens I heard you issues the first 3 times you said them. Still disagree.